# CSS Body Tag for OnUnload?

Tags: css

I have a page that needs an "OnUnload" attribute for the  tag. I know how to make it work for a normal  tag:

```
<body onunload="offline()">
```

however, in this particular case, I am using a CSS-styled tag, which is set up like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
body 
{
background-image:url('<?php echo $profile[24]; ?>');center;
<?php
if($profile[25]{0}=="F") echo "background-repeat:no-repeat;"; //You can ignore this
if($profile[25]{1}=="T") echo "background-size:100% 100%;";   //entire PHP script, it
if($profile[25]{2}=="T") echo "background-attachment:fixed;"; //isn't important.
?>
}
</style>
```

What I need, is for an "OnUnload" attribute to work along with that format.

I've tried Google many different times, worded many different ways, and I've even found a similar question in another forum (it was left unanswered). But as far as I can tell, this attribute doesn't actually exist in CSS format. I'm assuming that's wrong, however, which is why I'm here.

Please let me know what I can do about it, even if I have to ditch the CSS format. I think it might still be able to work in standard http format, but I know this code here works the way it is, so I'd rather not mess with it if I don't have to.

Comment: Please try to reword your question, it is hard to tell what you are looking for? you want to know when the <style> tag has loaded? afaik there is no CSS selector for :load ??

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to do. You may be confused about the respective roles of HTML, Javascript and CSS in a webpage, or you might just be wording it wrongly. There are no attributes in CSS, and `onunload` is about Javascript, not CSS.

Comment: Re your edit: it seems like you think you can either put a `<body>` start tag in the HTML, or a `body` selector in the stylesheet, but not both? Or am I totally off?

Comment: so it appears you want the onunload to function for elements such as `<img>` and `<div>` ?? in which case **dafuq** is all this CSS mumbo-jumbo

Comment: My <body> tag is set up in the CSS style you see above, and I need it to include a way to execute the JS function "offline()" on page unload.

Comment: @rlemon where do you get the `<img>` and `<div>` from? I don't read that into the OP's question.

Comment: **cough cough** *"such as..."* - and see I was right. this question has nothing to do with CSS.

Comment: @Seriamus Please post your whole webpage somewhere. This is still totally confusing. You can't "set up a tag" in the CSS. What prevents you from putting `onunload="offline()"` in the body's start tag? It still seems you think you can either put a `<body>` start tag in the HTML, or a `body` selector in the stylesheet, but not both.

Comment: @Mr Lister
Thank you; that `onunload="offline()"` was exactly what I was asking for -- I had tried it before, but I guess I must have misspelled it or something. I couldn't find it anywhere on the internet, but I tried it again in my code, and now it works!

Comment: @Seriamus You do realise I copied that from the question?

Comment: @Mr Lister That's funny; I thought you were offering it as an answer, which is why I tried it again. But again, it must have been a spelling error or something that made me think it didn't work the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function offline(){
        //whatever
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = offline;
</script>
```